# Why the copy constructor is not called in this code?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class myclass
{
  private:
    int x;
  public:
    myclass(int value=0):x{value}{
        cout<<"Default constructor is called\n";
    }

    myclass(const myclass& ref_obj)
    {
        cout<<"Copy constructor is called\n";
        x=ref_obj.x;
    }
    int getx(){return x;};

};


int main()
{
    myclass obj3(myclass(100));
    cout<<obj3.getx();
    return 0;
}
```

Getting the output:

```
Default constructor is called
100
```

I am expecting the copy constructor to be called along with the default constructor.  Why is the copy constructor not running in this case?

Answer (score 8):

This is a result of **[Copy elison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)**.

In the statement `myclass obj3(myclass(100));`, the compiler is smart enough to know that the temp object created by `myclass(100)` is not actually needed to initialize `obj3` and is optimizing the temp away, effectively turning the statement into `myclass obj3(100);`

Comment: Thanks Let me check that :)